# keycloak javascript adapter request offline token

Tags: javascript, offline, keycloak

I have js application for which I use keycloak 1.7-final JavaScript adapter with public client and standard flow and it works fine but now I wanted to add offline capability to the application and don't know how to get offline token. according to the [documentation](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/timeouts.html#offline-access) the client can request offline token by adding parameter "scope=offline_access" when sending authorization request to Keycloak.
The thing is I don't know where to add the parameter. I tried to add to "keycloak.config" and "keycloak.init" but its not working.

in keycloak.config:

```
keycloak: {
     url: 'link omitted',
     realm: 'sisdn-realm',
     clientId: 'sisdn',
     redirect_uri: 'link omitted',
     flow: 'standard',
     'enable-cors': true,
     scope: 'offline_access'
}
```

and in keycloak.init

```
const keycloakConf = require('keycloak')//this is the same config above
var keycloak = new  keycloakConf(config.keycloak)

keycloak.init({
   onLoad: 'login-required',
   checkLoginIframe: false,
   scope: 'offline_access'
})
.success(authenticated => {
   if(!authenticated)
     dispatch(loginFailure())
   else {
     global.keycloak = keycloak
     dispatch(loginSuccess())
    }
 })
```

Comment: You have to add the "scope=offline_access" directly in the authorization request itself. Could you add the code you're using to send the request ?

Comment: this is the authorization request itself as you can see from my edit that's what I use to issue the request

Comment: The doc refers to an `offline-access-app` example, did you take a look at it ?

Comment: yes, its java application and it add the scope=offline_access directly to the query parameter but I couldn't see how it might help with the javascript adapter

Comment: I would have put this question in the issues in github repository but the funny thing there is no issue tab in the repository

Comment: Maybe that option can't be set using the Javascript adapter ? Did you look at the JS adapter code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JS adapter code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-js-bower/blob/master/dist/keycloak.js):

The `init`  method doesn't accept the `scope` option, but the `login` method does.

Comment: You're right about the scope option so I had to use init() then in the callback I call login if the user is not logged in, thanks.

Comment: @mhashim can you post your solution ? how can you init() without login so you can request offline access ?